# Use Exceljs in meteor Application

Tags: node.js, exceljs

In my meteor project i want to read a excel file and get the data so i used this code to do that in server - > index.js file

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import Excel from 'exceljs';
Meteor.startup(() => {
 // code to run on server at startup
 var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
 const filename = '/home/xxx/Projects/app.xlsx';
 workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename)
   .then(function() {
      var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheet);
      worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) 
       {
         console.log("Row " + rowNumber + " = " +   
        JSON.stringify(row.values));
       });
     });
  });
```

but this doesn't work this gives

```
throw new Error('Unexpected xml node in parseOpen: ' +    
JSON.stringify(node));
```

how can i read the data can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text, you can use textract for node:

```
var textract = require('textract');

textract.fromFileWithPath('/home/xxx/Projects/app.xlsx', function( error, text ) {

    console.log(text);

})
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract